# Should repositories be implemented as singletons as best practice?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, repository

I have a small webapp that uses `EntityFramework` to store stuff via repositories into the database.

What I've done so far (based on all the tutorials I read) is create a repository where I need it, as shown below:

In `CustomMembershipProvider`:

```
    public CustomMembershipProvider()
    {
        _userRepository = new UserRepository(new TenantApplicationContext());
    }
```

In my `RegisterController`:

```
    public TenantRepository TenantRepository { get; set; }
    public UserRepository UserRepository { get; set; }

    protected override void Initialize(RequestContext requestContext)
    {
        if (MembershipService == null) { MembershipService = new AccountMembershipService(); }
        if (TenantRepository == null) { TenantRepository = new TenantRepository(TenantApplicationContext); }
        if (UserRepository == null) { UserRepository = new UserRepository(TenantApplicationContext); }

        base.Initialize(requestContext);
    }
```

The point is, that I instantiate the `UserRepository` twice. This becomes a problem when I create a `User` in one instance, and try to retrieve it in the other instance, **and I did not call** `SaveChanges` in between.

The problem lies here:

```
// Snippet from the register controller class

if (!UserRepository.Exists(model.AccountableEmailAddress))
{
    // 1 - Create the user via a custom MembershipProvider
    // Note, the CustomMembershipProvider has it's own instance of UserRepository

    var createStatus = MembershipService.CreateUser(
        model.AccountableUser,
        model.Password,
        model.AccountableEmailAddress);

    if (createStatus == MembershipCreateStatus.Success)
    {
        // Left out irrelevant code

        AdministerUserAndTenant(tenant.Name, model.AccountableEmailAddress);
    }
}

private void AdministerUserAndTenant(string tenantName, string emailAddress)
{
    // 2 - Try to retrieve the user from a different (!) instance of UserRepository
    var user = UserRepository.GetUser(emailAddress);
    var tenant = TenantRepository.GetTenantByName(tenantName);
    tenant.Users.Add(user);
    TenantApplicationContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

I hope you can still follow, tried to leave out unnecessary parts.

What is the best way to deal with issues like this?

PS: I'm not very fond of the `Singleton` pattern, so if possible don't go there :).

Comment: Why would you? Having them as singletons doesn't solve any specific problem, does it?

Comment: well, that would solve the part where I always work with the same repository instance. So I would be able to retrieve uncommitted objects.

Comment: Just centralize the access to repositories. No need to have them as singletons.

Comment: Hmm, kinda found out that the only problem I can't solve is that I want to use the same repository in the `CustomMembershipProvider` instance. Should I delete this question all together and create a new one? Or is it acceptable to update it (which will be pretty much a make-over)

Comment: If it is a makeover, that wouldn't be fair on the person that answered. New question time ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When exactly does it become a problem? Cause that's where the answer lies. Classes that should know of each other's unsaved changes should use the same repository instance. Since they are probably related, you'll manage passing a reference between them.

If there's reason why all of your application should have one single repository, use Dependency Injection.

Comment: And even when the whole app shouldn't have a single repository - use DI :)

Comment: Ah, good point. The problem is that the CustomMembershipProvider is created for me, I don't think I'm able to pass the reference. It's magically created for me by the framework. PS: updated my question with some additional code. Hope it makes sense

Comment: i'll accept your answer, new one incoming tho, you helped me figure out what the underlying problem is.